# Show that variable lies in specific interval

Tags: probability, proof-writing

For a project of mine, I (for the moment) want to prove that a function satisfies a specific constraint. As far as I have constructed the proof, this seems to boil down to show that a variable lies in a specific interval, but at that point I am stuck, because, as a non-mathematician, I don't know how to prove the next step. So I assume the following:

There are three probability functions (defined on propositional logic instead of sets) with a simple domain of three elements:

For i={1,2,3}:

$P_i: \{A, B, A \land B\} \rightarrow [0,1]$

Moreover, I assume that the following holds:

$P_i(A) = a_i$

$P_i(B) = b_i$

$P_i(A \land B) = c_i \in [max(0,a_i + b_i -1), min(a_i,b_i)]$

Now, I have another function which maps the input of these three functions onto a single probability distribution:

$F: [0,1]^3 \rightarrow [0,1]$

$F(x,y,z) = \frac{x+y+z}{3}$

What I want to show (or test whether it holds) is the following:

$F(c_1, c_2, c_3)  \in [max(0,F(a_1,a_2,a_3) + F(b_1,b_2,b_3) -1), min(F(a_1,a_2,a_3),F(b_1,b_2,b_3))]$

The next step I took is transforming the above equation (I might have gone wrong here already):

$\frac{c_1+c_2+c_3}{3} \in [max(0,\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{3} + \frac{b_1+b_2+b_3}{3} -1), min(\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{3}, \frac{b_1+b_2+b_3}{3})]$

But here I am confused how to continue, partly because I don't know how to further transform the statement which has min/max functions in it. I was thinking about getting the interval by making a case distinction and showing what it would be in the minimal and in the maximal case but I just did not figure out how to.

I would be very very grateful about someone giving me a helpful hint! I suppose it is quite trivial, and I just don't see it.. Thanks in advance!